# Trouble with inheritance: Separate table implementation for disjoint entities and common ID

Tags: database-design, subtypes

I currently have four disjoint entity types (competition, talk, award, publication) that are to be converted to tables. In order to manage certain other data for each, i.e. documents related to each entity (many documents per entry), should I create a separate table to get a common ID and then assign them resulting in costly joins or is there another method? My database course faculty taught me to make separate tables for disjoint relationships but I don't know what is the best choice here.

I understand this is a common question but I unfortunately am unable to find a proper solution or advice anywhere.

---

<sub>I apologize if this is a duplicate. Thank you for taking your time to answer.</sub>

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44355/24505

Comment: What is the basis for assuming joins are costly? Usually they are only costly if there is not a covering index or if the data types of the columns being joined on are not the same. Trying to query from a design that contorts the structure in an effort to avoid joins is usually what ends up being costly.